# Get correct NSRect in NSTextView when image insert

Tags: macos, nstextview, appkit

I use [NSTextView firstRectForCharacterRange:actualRange:] 
and [NSLayoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:] get cursor rect, it works right when only pure text in NSTextView.

But when I insert image to text view,  [NSTextView firstRectForCharacterRange:actualRange:] return wrong result(NSRectZero), and [NSLayoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:] return right value in TextView but convert to superview is wrong.

only when the image is bigger than textview bounds happen.

Anyone knows about how to resolve that?

Comment: I found the problem, insert change NSParagraphStyle codes in didChangeText function, will become that

Comment: I change this codes order, fix that